# How to convert a PNG tile set into the Mbtiles format

Tags: tilemill, mapbox, mbtiles

I have exported a folder with PNGs tiles and I want to convert them into `Mbtiles` format to use with Mapbox (maybe via TileMill?). How can I do that?

Is there a convertor where I can specify the parent folder and all subdirectories with their respective PNGs to be converted into Mbtiles format? Thanks!

Comment: Are they PNG's from an ArcGIS tileset?

Comment: @mapBaker they’re from http://www.maptiler.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MBUtil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil/) is a command-line utility that can pack a directory of tiles into a MBTiles file and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way. I tried and it worked like a charm.
http://mapit-gis.com/generating-mbtiles-from-an-image/